# Autocomplete off

Tags: html

I want to make an Input field secure, so enforced autocomplete off.

1)But  intelligent user using modern browsers can edit webpage dynamically and enable autocomplete on. (f12)

What is the best way to accomplish my Task. Client script won't solve my solution?

Any ideas and solutions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't stop it. You don't have enough control over the browser *or the user* to effectively stop someone who doesn't want to be stopped. The best you can use is the tools you have (turning autocomplete off, some JavaScript, etc) and keep the number of users who bypass this to a minimum, but not zero.

Not to mention, this really is down to user choice. If they want to have an autofill for their browser, that's their call. If they want to make it very simple to put sensitive information into a web form so be it. The same goes for enabling JavaScript, stylesheets, screen resolution, etc.

Comment: What if multiple workers uses same machine to login, user-id can be compromised, our client uses emp-id for login not great idea on their part though.

Comment: It's not, but you can't control that much less stop it. You make it secure on your end, and do your best to help users keep it secure on there's. That's all you can do.

Comment: umm, makes sense. But why can't web browses restrict few attributes from editing (I am just asking, not questioning :-) , please consider this as discussion)

Comment: They do by letting you turn autocomplete off. But they don't control the OS or the user, both of which can bypass the browser and your code. It's just the nature of the Web.

Comment: Consider that this isn't just a problem with browsers. A sufficiently intelligent and motivated user can edit the client program that they are running on their computer, or even write a different program that responds to your server in the same way. Your only recourse is to have complete control over the client computer.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try following option in your html instead of autocomplete="off"**

```
<input type="text" name="firstName"  autocomplete="new-password"/>
```

This is working fine for me, Please try this solution.